# What does the dollar sign ('$') mean when in the string to .query?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, terminology, node-postgres, dollar-sign

What does the `$` sign mean in this statement:

```
// SQL Query > Update Data
client.query('UPDATE items SET text=($1), complete=($2) WHERE id=($3)',
[data.text, data.complete, id]);
```

Comment: i'm beginner on node.js for this reason i'm asking this question i know that it is like an  Alias  but i don't know what it means exactly 
i spend more than 2 hours to search but i find anything :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty universally in that context it's called a *"placeholder"*. You got that code from this [blog entry](http://mherman.org/blog/2015/02/12/postgresql-and-nodejs/). You can see there that `client` is defined above in the callback to `pg.connect`,

```
pg.connect(connectionString, (err, client, done) => {
```

Looking up in that blog entry, `pg` is defined here

```
const pg = require('pg');
```

You can always find out what an npm-installed module name resolves to by doing a [quick search](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg). In this case though the blog openly says they're using [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres). Which documents this under,

- [*Paramaterized Queries*](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#parameterized-query)

*Paramaterized* means *accepting of a parameter*. That parameter's placement is defined with a *"placeholder"* as specified with `$`. The purpose of this is often to save time in *planning* and to avert SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Hi @Evan Carroll i have just a question can you see if you have a response [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49150477/update-postgreql-database-with-node-js)
thank you