# Update PostgreSQL database with Node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sql-update, parameterized-query

I am trying to update a PostgreSQL table so for that I'm creating two arrays:

```js
var name_ = []; 
var id_ = [];
```

Then I create a `forEach` loop where `MyRow` is a query that contains different data:

```js
MyRow.rows.forEach(function(row){
    name_.push(row.name);
    id_.push(row.id);
});
var updateAccount = 'UPDATE myTable SET myRow =$1 '+
    'where id = $2'
client.query(updateAccount,[name_.toString(),id_.toString()],false).then(function(err,result){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.stack);
    } else {
        console.log(name_)
    }
});
```

Then I get an error:

> error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "myTable "

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the error is related, but where is `shema` mentioned? Also use backticks, [`oneLine`](https://github.com/declandewet/common-tags#oneline) and `const` on template strings.

```
const updateAccount = oneLine`
   UPDATE myTable
   SET myRow = $1
   WHERE shema.id = $2  -- where is `shema` defined?
`;
```

Comment: thank you for your response
 
   - shema mean just the path but i guess that it is not mandatory
   - what do you mean by oneline?

Comment: i steel have a problem on the import
import {oneLine} from 'common-tags';
that allow me to use the oneLine 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import?

Comment: You need to use @std/esm until node supports mjs/import. https://github.com/standard-things/esm

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that you should enclose your values in single quotes.

```
var updateAccount = "UPDATE myTable SET myRow = '$1' "+
"where shema.id = '$2'"
```

In your example, your values are interpreted as column names, so PostgreSQL asks you to specify a table containing these.

Comment: thank you for your response but i have the sames error

Comment: What about that `shema.id` ? Is that another table ?
I'm not totally sure about what you're trying to do in this code

Comment: shema represents just the path of the table